# Minimum and maximum of $Tr(\rho\sigma)+\sqrt{1-Tr(\rho^2)}\sqrt{1-Tr(\sigma^2)}$

Tags: density-matrix, linear-algebra

How do I find the maximum and minimum of the following expression?
$$F_N(\rho,\sigma)=Tr(\rho\sigma)+\sqrt{1-Tr(\rho^2)}\sqrt{1-Tr(\sigma^2)}.$$
I think of using this inequality
$$Tr(\rho\sigma)\leq Tr(\rho)tr(\sigma),$$
so that
$$F_N\leq Tr(\rho)Tr(\sigma)+\sqrt{1-Tr(\rho^2)}\sqrt{1-Tr(\sigma^2)},$$
where $\rho=\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ b&c \end{bmatrix}$ and $\sigma=\begin{bmatrix} d&e \\ e&f \end{bmatrix}$.

I don't know if that's the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework question. So I just give some hints.

In order to minimize
$$F_N(\rho,\sigma)=Tr(\rho\sigma)+\sqrt{1-Tr(\rho^2)}\sqrt{1-Tr(\sigma^2)}$$
choose $\sigma$ and $\rho$ to be pure and orthogonal states. Then $F_N(\rho, \sigma)=0$. Recall that if $\rho$ is pure, we have $Tr(\rho^2)=1$ and we can express it as $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. Same applies to $\sigma$, i.e., we can write $\sigma=|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|$. Given what I've stated above, what should be the relation between $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$?

In order to maximize $F_N$, you definitely don't want one of your density matrices to be pure because the right-most term will be zero. With the right choice of density matrices, you can get $F_N(\rho, \sigma)=1$. Recall what the maximally mixed state is.